# Css position sticky, overlaps instead of pushing

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am having hard time, to understand why sticky div does not push other sticky div.
And I am pretty sure I have seen it working like that, but I can't figure that out.

I want Header 1 to push Header 2 not overlap on it.
HTML

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h1>Item1</h1>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h1>Item2</h1>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Header 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h1>Item1</h1>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h1>Item2</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: bold 20vw Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
}
```

Here is an example and what I am trying to do.
https://jsfiddle.net/7zfq491o/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need different wrapper:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font: bold 20vw Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}

.item {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item2</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item2</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```